# How can I create a "LAN Chat" app using Silverlight for Windows Phone (or Silverlight)?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, sockets, chat, lan

I would create a chat to send text from my Windows Phone (Server) to my Notebook (Client), both connected via WiFi on the LAN. Is there a way to do it? I think I have to use Sockets but I have no idea how to do it and the tutorials found on the web doesn't do what I think.. Thanks

Comment: I can think of a few ways you could do this - why dont you write down in english how you think it should work - specifically how your web page can go and get any new messages waiting for it and update your question, so you have some pseudo code, and maybe then you can write some actual code and come back with a coding issue

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need windows phone to be the server?

If windows phone can host WCF services this sounds like a good solution:
http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/SilverlightTV/Duplex-communication-with-WCF-in-Silverlight-4-Silverlight-TV-34/